# Simple Scala JSON library for non-recursive case classes

Tags: json, scala, spray-json, argonaut

I have case classes that only contain Strings or collections of Strings and want to convert them to JSON objects with corresponding field names plus an additional field to denote the type.

```
sealed trait Item
case class ProductX(a: String, b: String) extends Item
case class ProductY(a: String, b: String) extends Item
case class CollX(els: List[String]) extends Item
case class CollY(els: List[String]) extends Item
```

Most libs have special support for case classes but there never seems to be a way to use that in conjunction with an additional type field to disambiguate the isomorphic cases, and I'd have to fall back to the more low-level descriptions.

So far I've tried spray-json and argonaut and I wind up with way more boilerplate than my simple usage scenario would justify:

```
// spray-json

implicit object CollXJsonFormat extends RootJsonFormat[CollX] {
  def write(ss: CollX) = JsObject(
    "type" -> JsString("CollX"),
    "els"  -> JsArray(ss.els.map(JsString(_)): _*)
  )
  def read(value: JsValue) = {
    value.asJsObject.getFields("type", "els") match {
      case Seq(JsString("CollX"), JsArray(els)) =>
        CollX(els.toList.map({
          case JsString(s) => s
          case _ => throw new DeserializationException("JsString expected")
        }))
      case _ => throw new DeserializationException("CollX expected")
    }
  }
}
```

For argonaut I couldn't even figure out how to match the type field since `DecodeResult` has no filter method:

```
// argonaut

implicit def CollXCodec: CodecJson[CollX] =
  CodecJson(
    (px: CollX) =>
      ("type" := "CollX") ->:
      ("els" := px.els) ->:
      jEmptyObject,
    c => for {
      t <- (c --\ "type").as[String]
      els <- (c --\ "els").as[List[String]]
    } yield CollX(els))
```

Is there another lib that can handle this better or is there some feature in one of these libs I've overlooked that would significantly reduce the boilerplate?

Comment: I've used json4s successfully in the past.

Comment: I'd suggest staying far away from reflection-y JSON libraries like json4s and lift-json. Check out [play-json-variants](https://github.com/julienrf/play-json-variants) for a nice example of how to handle this problem in a much cleaner way.

Comment: thanks @TravisBrown, hits the nail on the head!

Answer (score 0):

I use: net.liftweb with very good results.

You can create json this way. 
For example if you have:

```
case class ABjsontemplate(a: String, b: String)
```

You can create the json like this:

```
net.liftweb.json.Serialization.write(ABjsontemplate("a", "b"))
```

in SBT:

```
libraryDependencies += "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "3.0-M1"
```

I hope it can help.